# how to convert a python datetime.datetime into a list

Tags: python, datetime

I have a datetime.datetime object.  All I want to do is pull it's data out and put it into a list.  The only method I have found is:

```
date_list=list(my_dt_ob.timetuple())
```

This seems to be an awfully convoluted way of doing a conceptually simple thing.  Anyone have a better way?  Thanks.

Comment: Define "better"? What you've shown looks perfectly adequate to me.

Comment: Seems pretty direct to me... Why do you even need it as a list? You can enumerate a tuple in all the same ways you would a list.

Comment: It's just that, first I'm converting to a timetuple(), and then from that to a list.  I was expecting -- and you can probably tell that I am new to python -- that there would be a one-shot command for turning a commonly used thing like datetime.datetime into a commonly used thing like a list.  Actually, I probably can just stick with the tuple, per Travis Giggs, now that I think about it.

Comment: Why not keep it as a tuple?
Tuples are much faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each of the parts of the date and time are available as attributes of the `datetime` object. You can use them directly:

```
date_list = [my_dt_ob.year, my_dt_ob.month, my_dt_ob.day, my_dt_ob.hour, my_dt_ob.minute, my_dt_ob.second]
```

Comment: his solution is better date_list=list(my_dt_ob.timetuple())

Comment: @locojay, I thought so too but since there's an alternative I thought it needed to be presented.

Comment: k one could also convert to iso_format and then use a regex incase there was no timetuple. One would the avoid to type to much